# Are questions about Mr. Robot on topic?

Tags: discussion

I asked the question [Is Mr. Robot in Elliot's head?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/96327/is-mr-robot-in-elliots-head?noredirect=1#comment222112_96327). There's a comment and a close vote that it is off topic. Now, I firmly believe that this show is considered at least Sci-Fi, as do many other sites on the internet. Dictionary.com states the definition as:

"A form of fiction that draws imaginatively on scientific knowledge and speculation in its plot, setting, theme, etc."

This show fits that definition. It's also been labeled as Cyberpunk, which is a sub-genre of sci-fi. As I stated, just because there's no spaceships or aliens doesn't make this show any less sci-fi.

Comment: It may be a subgenre of Sci-Fi, but, if so, its Cyberpunk elements have yet to show themselves. I really like *Mr Robot*, but I don't think it's Sci-Fi or Cyberpunk (And where does it say Cyberpunk is a derivative of Sci-Fi anyway? Just curious.).

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to say no.

The show has been marketed by [USA Network](http://www.usanetwork.com/mrrobot/cast) (among others) as

> contemporary and culturally resonant drama.

There don't seem to be any substantial science-fictional or fantasical elements aside from the "[hollywood hacking](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HollywoodHacking)" (warning, TV Tropes link) and even that's toned down to the absolute minimum, according to the [show's creator](http://www.npr.org/2015/06/21/415517808/the-human-drama-of-hacking-fuels-tv-thriller-mr-robot);

> So I was a nerd growing up, and I was a big techie and I watched all
>   of those terrible movies and all those terrible television shows. And
>   it was actually, I think, more work to portray it as poorly as they
>   did because they forced all these CGI graphics and all this ridiculous
>   stuff to force the drama there. One of the rules I have on my show is
>   that we don't green screen ... anything. So everything you see that we
>   filmed is real. And so the actors, I really wanted them to react to
>   what is actually going on on-screen.
>
> But I gotta be honest, I'm not some genius over here, I'm just
>   actually going through what a programmer or coder or cybersecurity
>   engineer would do in a certain hack. And the funny thing is, even
>   though people don't completely understand it, they get it. And it's
>   almost like when you watch a medical drama, or a legal drama or
>   whatever, I don't necessarily understand all of the terminology, but I
>   get what's going on emotionally, I get what the stakes are.

Comment: This show is by far less of the hollywood hacking than say, Scorpion. It might not be high sci-fi, but I definitely see it being on topic for here.

Comment: @MyCodeSucks - See edit. The creator is aware that the hacking is a bit dramatic, but he wants to keep it grounded.

Comment: But it is a "cyberpunk" show, which is a sub-genre of sci-fi.

Comment: The hacking may be a little dramatic or fantastical, but so are most of the dramatic events in *Malcolm in the Middle*, which isn't on-topic, even though many of the events could never happen in real life (like Craig surviving past the first few seasons).

Answer (score 5):

As someone who's actually watching the show, I'll add my 2 cents.  It's not sci-fi at all. It's very clearly set in a modern day real-world setting with no fantastical elements.  It's as grounded as grounded can be, they go far out of their way to maintain accuracy on the many technology and computer elements, especially compared other computer-centric shows on TV.

There are certain cyberpunk elements.  While Evil Corp is meant to be a satire of actual corporations, it's not being as unrealistically over the top as, for example, the TV networks in *Max Headroom*.  So I wouldn't call that element fantastical.

So no, it's not sci-fi (and certainly not fantasy), and so it is off-topic.

The only possible fantastical element is what that linked question asks about, is Mr. Robot an imaginary person in Elliot's head?  Which is why I didn't vote to close it, but did migrate another *Mr. Robot* question that was recently posted here.